# Correct procedure to change location of asset compilation with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to change from having `Heroku` pre-compile the assets to pre-compiling them on development and pushing them to `Heroku`. I understand the basic procedure is

```
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  git add .
  git commit -m 'Add precompiled Assets'
  git push production master
```

However, this wipes out any existing assets on heroku. For instance, images referenced in old emails are wiped out. Is there a way to do this and provide a continuity with legacy assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some help from Heroku support and the comments from [Schneems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147390/schneems) below, here is the non-answer I came to.

- Unless you understand the intricacies of managing your assets with sprockets, precompile on heroku rather than locally.
- Whether you precompile locally or heroku, use a CDN and set far future expire dates on your assets.
- Use the latest version of sprockets (3.7.1 as the time of writing this post).
- If you precompile locally, be aware that sprockets does keep the last three copies of the assets around, and keep in mind it is up to you to keep your assets consistent with the last release.
- There are many edge cases, so there is no such thing as a simple answer that suits the stack overflow format.

So in summary, unless you are highly knowledgeable or courageous, do not precompile locally.

And finally, use a CDN.

Comment: Don't do the clobber, it will kill all of your assets and not give you any of the old assets. Running `assets:clean` after you've generated assets is what the buildpack does.

Comment: The reasoning in regard to using clobber is that the local assets can get way out of sync with the Heroku assets as you go through a debug cycle. So the clobber gets rid of anything suspect, then checkout the assets from that were last pushed to Heroku. That way you are in sync. Then precompile, then perhaps do a assets:clean?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `rake assets:precompile` in development mode. Sprockets is set to generate assets on the fly. If you do generate these files, don't check those assets in. If you use `assets:clobber` then you kill the feature where sprockets keeps up to 3 older copies of your assets. The only reason to check in your assets to deploy to Heroku is if you have an extremely rare case and need extremely tight grained asset control. Or you are using it as a temporary debugging tool. There's an extremely large number of edge cases.

Comment: I do not use rake assets:precompile in development mode, but I do use it on my local machine in production mode. This is to run my server in production mode on my local machine, and also prior to pushing to my Heroku staging server. In later case I do need to check the assets in. It sounds to me that if I am doing this sort of activity, I should checkout out a new branch, and then revert to the master branch to do the precompile, assets:clean, and push to the Heroku production server.